# Python 2 lists merge into 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, list, merge, linked-list, concatenation

I have two list

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
```

I want to new 2 dimensional list

```
c=[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

how can I concatenate 2 lists?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` function combined with `list` comprehension to get `list` of `list`s rather than `list` of `tuple`s, that is:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c=[list(i) for i in zip(a,b)]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is efficient. But it should work:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append([a[i], b[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as easily as:

```
[*map(list, zip(a, b))]
```

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

That's it!

The `*` unpacks all zipped items into a list, and `list` is the callable that will be applied to each result of the `zip`.

This would do the same, and might be a little nicer for the eye:

```
list(map(list, zip(a, b)))
```